# How to identify notebook motherboard parts that don't have meaningful description?

Tags: identification, laptop

Recently I was trying to fix flooded laptop - Dell Inspiron 5370. After disassembling the motherboard (named ARMANI13) I noticed rust on one of the chips. Its location and surrounding elements suggest its somehow related to power management. However there aren't any meaningful part numbers on top of it. I tried looking for it in electronic suppliers catalog, googling all possible combinations of letters on top, but did not get any useful results.

I tried many combinations:
5X-4H, 5X=4H, M3Y etc.

In the first step I will try to remove it, clear and solder back. But I think it's possible the chip got damaged or its pins got eaten by rust. In such case I will have to buy a new one.

I also hadn't found any used / damaged motherboards with same chip and reasonable prices. New stock motherboard costs 80% of new laptop so the only sane way is to replace single broken part.

Not surprisingly I wasn't able to find any schematics of this or related motherboards.

Is there any way to identify such part? The only useful detail is the package.

Is it possible that a dedicated integrated circuit was manufactured for this specific kind of motherboard only and it's not accessible on market?

[image: 5X-4H M3Y]

Comment: how do you know that it is rust?

Comment: what else could it be?

Answer (score 1):

I got response on another board.
Part is RT6575D - DC/DC converter